# Java/Android: Passing Intent Extras, then use it on another method

Tags: java, android

Hello again everyone,
This time I have a problem with Intent & Extras.

here's my first activity

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(RoomSetting.this, App.class);
i1.putExtra("subposition1", "right");
final int result=1;
startActivityForResult(i1, result);
```

and in the 2nd activity I try to get "subposition1" value

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccVals = new Number3d(); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1");
}
```

My question is, how can I use SubPos on another method?

Sorry for noobish question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to the method or make it an instance variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call this on your "other method".

```
String subposition = getIntent().getStringExtra("subposition1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String SubPos;
// declare SubPos String as class variable and you can access anywhere in class<<<
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccVals = new Number3d(); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1");
}

public void anotherMethod(){
//here you can access it...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

declare **SubPos**  before `onCreate` as:

```
public String SubPos=null; // or you can also declare it as static as your need
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccVals = new Number3d(); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1");
}


   public void testmethod()
   {
      String str=SubPos; //get SubPos value  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways of doing it easyly:

First way: Use a global variable for the class:

```
   String SubPos;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccVals = new Number3d(); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1"); //note that I've deleted the 'String'
}
```

2n way: Pass to the method the variable:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccVals = new Number3d(); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1");
    otherMethod(SubPos);
}

public void otherMethod(String s) {
    //do stuff.
}
```

I considered that maybe you want this variable in another class, then you could do it adding this function (having the String SubPos as global in the class):

```
   String SubPos;
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    mAccVals = new Number3d(); 
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1"); //note that I've deleted the 'String'
   }
    public String getSubPos() {
        return SubPos;
    }
```

This way you can call the     instanceOfTheClass.getSubPos() in any other class that has the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String SubPos = extras.getString("subposition1");
```

with

```
String SubPos = getIntent().getStringExtra("subposition1");
```